# use curl to post "using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

Tags: api, curl, post

i used infomaniak api, infomaniak which is a provider of domain. i try to change ip of the subnetdomain by the infomaniak api,
first i used my browser but not work,

after that i tried to use curl to change the ip in my subdomain for this i try this :

i tried to change the password with a easy password but not work,

```
curl https://webmaster@geo-satis.com:my_password@infomaniak.com/nic/update?hostname=sub_domain&myip=1.2.3.4

curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

Answer (score 1):

`@` signs in your user name (or password) need to be URL encoded as `%40`. The at-sign is used as a separator between the credentials and the host name.